# Regular expression matching in php

Tags: php, regex

I have this regexp:

```
/(.*)(([0-9]([^a-zA-Z])*){7,}[0-9])(.*)/.
```

Given the following values

```
0654535263
065453-.-5263
065asd4535263
```

### Expected Results

```
06**** 
06****
06****
```

### Actual Results

```
0654535263
06****
065asd4535263
```

### It does not match the last row because of the letters (I want to match from 0-3 letters) and it matches only last occurence (in the second row in example, it skips first row).

First of all thank u all oyur answers are very helpfull and i owe u a bih time. I cant create array of numbers and mask them like that because i can have string like this:

I am John, I live bla bla my phone is: 0, 6, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 2, 6 - 3 -- 065asd4535263.

To simplify i want to hide entered mobile number.

I had two problems:

1. change regxp mentioned above, to hide digits separated by no more than 3 chars.
2. preg_replace was replacing only one occurence.

At the end i just need regexp to replace any array of digits, at least 6 digits long, separated by any number of special chars (12--654-5, 453/--222, 23....5645 etc) OR no more than 3 chars (ltters) (06asd453, 123as562).

Thank you again, all answers are vry helpfull, but i am gulty because i didnt formulated my question right.

p.s. i cant give u reputation because i must have at least 15, as soon as i get that much, i will 'vote up', all answers deserve it.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish. Your regex has barely anything to do with "I want to match from 0 to 3 letters". Could you provide some more input examples (especially ones, that should fail) and go into more detail what the conditions for a match are?

Comment: `preg_replace('/([0-9]{2})\S+[0-9]/m','$1****',$string);` would achieve the results you ask for in this question, but as @m.buettner stated, since we don't know when it's supposed to fail, it will almost definitely match false positives.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm why so complicated when you only want to mascarade your string.

```
$input = '0654535263';
$input = substr($input, 0, 2);
$output = $input . '********';
```

Its a bit easier when you only want the first 2 characters of your string. Perhaps your solution had another sin. But this is a bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `substr_replace`

```
 echo substr_replace($v, "****", 2);
```

Example

```
$list = array("0654535263","065453-.-5263","065asd4535263");
echo "<pre>";
foreach ( $list as $v ) {
    echo substr_replace($v, "****", 2), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
06****
06****
06****
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the reason you want to use regular expressions is so that you don't mask every string that you get. This regex checks that there is at least 2 digits in the beginning of the string, then 0 to 3 alphabet characters, and then all the rest of the characters of the string need to be non-alphabet characters. If it matches, it masks the string, otherwise it says the string does not match.

```
$string = '0654535263';
if(preg_match('~^(\d{2})\d*?[a-zA-Z]{0,3}[^a-zA-Z]*$~', $string))
  $answer = preg_replace('~^(\d{2})\d*?[a-zA-Z]{0,3}[^a-zA-Z]*$~', '$1****', $string);
else
  $answer = $string . ' does not match';
print_r($answer); // 06****
```